# Count number of rows meeting multiple conditions in dataframe

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a question. I'm working on a database with patients and multiple conditions I scored as yes/no or numbers. I first counted the number of patients (rows) in which patients meet at least one criteria of 5, see this code (working):

```
nrow( df_1[df_1$tenderness_CS != 'no' | df_1$intoxication != 'no' |    
           df_1$focal_neuro_deficits != 'no' | df_1$EMV <= 13 | df_1$distr_injury != 'no',] )
```

But now I want to count how many patients meet 2, 3 and 4 criteria of the above standing. Doesn't matter which of the 5 criteria are met, just if 2 or 3 are met. I really don't know how to do that.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The logicals `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be treated like numerics 1 and 0.

So for example `TRUE+TRUE` is equal to 2.

So you can write:

```
nrow( df_1[df_1$tenderness_CS != 'no' + df_1$intoxication != 'no' +    
           df_1$focal_neuro_deficits != 'no' + (df_1$EMV <= 13) + df_1$distr_injury != 'no' %in% c(2,3,4),])
```

because this will first sum the results of each condition (1 when the condition is TRUE and 0 when it is FALSE) and then test whether the sum is in the vector `c(2,3,4)`.

Comment: This unfortunately produces an error: Error: unexpected '<=' in "             df_1$focal_neuro_deficits != 'no' + df_1$EMV <="

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```r
n_conditions <- (df_1$tenderness_CS != 'no') +
                (df_1$intoxication != 'no')  +   
                (df_1$focal_neuro_deficits != 'no') + 
                (df_1$EMV <= 13) +
                (df_1$distr_injury != 'no')
```

which will give you a vector of the number of conditions each patient met.

You can then do

```
table(n_conditions)
```

to show the times each number of conditions was met, and

```r
df_1[n_conditions == 3,]
```

To subset the dara frame to get only those patients who met 3 conditions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `+`, we can make use of `rowSums`.  The advantage is that it would also take of `NA` elements with `na.rm` argument i.e. if a particular column have NA in a row, it would result in `NA` if we do `+`

```
nm1 <- c("tenderness_CS", "intoxication",
                   "focal_neuro_deficits", "distr_injury")      
n_conditions <- rowSums(cbind(df_1[nm1] != "no", df_1$EMV <= 13), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now, we get the frequency of counts with `table`

```
table(n_conditions)
```